# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named matplotlib

Tags: pip, matplotlib

I have python version 2.7.15+ and also matplotlib version 2.1.1. But while running Python program, I'm still getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named matplotlib
```

I have tried all the pip and python commands to install matplotlib. But still it isn't working.

Comment: Run `sudo apt install python-matplotlib` and try again.

Comment: I have tried this several times but i am encountering the same issue